# C programming printing a linked list, not moving along list and crashing

Tags: c, list, printing

I am trying to print a linked list, it is acting strangely, when it is suppose to move to the next item it will not, for instance the first item printed is "Granny Smith" and then the rest in the struct, when it goes to the next line what should be a new food is "ranny Smith" Always without the G, and most of the other details are corrupted or gibberish. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define cls system("cls");
#define flush fflush(stdin)
#define pause system("pause");


struct food  // Declaration of struct
{
    char produce[20];
    char type[20];
    char soldBy[20];
    float price;
    int quantityInStock;
    struct food *next;
};


void addPres(struct food** tip, char tokenPro[20], char tokenType[20], char tokenSold[20], float tokenFloat, int tokenInt);
void display ();
void displayMenu ();
int getChoice ();
void readDataIn();




int main()
{
    int choice = 0;
    int ;
    struct food first;
    char *saveFloat, *saveInt;
    char tokenPro[20], tokenType[20], tokenSold[20], savePro[20], saveType[20], saveSold[20], j[1900];
    float tokenFloat, messFloat;
    int danint, tokenInt;
    struct food* a = NULL;
    FILE* file;

    a = NULL; // sets the first item on the list to empty

//readDataIn();
    do
    {
        choice = getChoice();//function to present choices and receive an answer
        switch (choice)//switch routes the choice
        {
        case 1: //to enter a new node on the list
            cls;
            printf("Enter the produce type: ");
            fgets(tokenPro, 20, stdin);
            printf("Enter the type: ");
            fgets(tokenType, 20, stdin);
            printf("Enter the units of measurement: ");
            fgets(tokenSold, 20, stdin);
            printf("\nEnter the price per %s: ", &tokenSold);
            scanf("%f", &tokenFloat );
            printf("\nEnter the quantity in stock: ");
            scanf("%i", &tokenInt );
            //pause;
            addPres(&a, tokenPro, tokenType, tokenSold, tokenFloat, tokenInt);
            break;
        case 2: //to display the linked list
            display(a);

            break;
        case 3: //to reverse the order

            if((file=fopen("AssignmentTwoInput.txt", "r")) != NULL)  //opens files
            {
                while(fgets(j, sizeof(j), file))  //while information is being sent to j from the file
                {
                    strcpy(savePro, strtok(j, ","));
                    strcpy(saveType, strtok(NULL, ","));
                    strcpy(saveSold, strtok(NULL, ","));
                    saveFloat = strtok(NULL, ",");
                    saveInt = strtok(NULL, "\n");
                    messFloat = atof(saveFloat); //ID number is assigned to token2
                    danint = atoi(saveInt); //converts  the value token2 points to into an int (previously read in as an string)
                    addPres(&a, savePro, saveType, saveSold, messFloat, danint); //sends the name and ID to the function to add a person
//printf("\n %s \t %s \t %s \t %f \t %i", savePro, saveType, saveSold, messFloat, danint);
//pause;
                }//end while loop
            }//end if loop
            printf("\nSuccessfully loaded input file\n\n\n"); //message to tell user the back was found and imported successfully
            pause;
            fclose(file);
            break;
        case 4: //to export data

            break;
        case 5: //option to exit

            exit(0);
            break;
        default://error checking
            printf("Please enter a valid choice.\n");
            break;
        }//switch loop close

    }
    while (choice != 5);   //end menu choices


    return 0;
}//end main


void addPres(struct food** tip, char tokenPro[20], char tokenType[20], char tokenSold[20], float tokenFloat, int tokenInt)
{


    struct food* temp =

        (struct food*) malloc(sizeof(struct food));
    strcpy(temp->produce, tokenPro);
    strcpy(temp->type, tokenType);
    strcpy(temp->soldBy, tokenSold);
    temp->price = tokenFloat;
    temp->quantityInStock = tokenInt;

//printf("\n %s \t %s \t %s \t %f \t %i", temp->produce, temp->type, temp->soldBy, temp->price, temp->quantityInStock);
//pause;
    if (tip == NULL) //if the tip node is empty
    {
        tip = temp; //tip node becomes this node
        (*tip)->next = NULL; // since there are no others yet the next node will be empty
    }


    else
    {
        temp->next = tip; // reassigns the tip node to the next one
        (*tip) = temp; //inserts current node as the tip
    }
}

void display(struct food* c)
{
//c = first; //assigns c to the first node on the linked list
    int count = 1;
    struct food *temp;
    temp = c;
    cls;
    printf("==========================================================================\n"); //prints a header to say which info is which
    printf(" Item #   Produce       Type             Sold By         Price    In Stock\n");
    printf("==========================================================================\n");
    while( c != NULL)
    {
        printf("%3i \t", count);
        printf("%s \t", c->produce ); //prints name
        printf("%s \t", c->type ); //prints name
        printf("%s \t", c->soldBy); //prints name
        printf("%-3.2f \t", c->price); //prints ID
        printf("%i\n", c->quantityInStock); //prints ID
        pause;
        count = count + 1;
        c = c->next; //advances to next item in the linked list

        if(c == NULL)
        {
            printf("\n end \n"); //once end is found user is told

            pause;
        }
    }
    printf("\n done \n");
    pause;
}//end display
```

Comment: This `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior, `fflush()` is for output streams... And `system("PAUSE")` is a windows only useless thing, use a real terminal emulator and just execute the program there so you don't need those wierd tricks.

Comment: Switch on warnings and pay attention to the information about incompatible pointer types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three important mistakes, one of them seems to be caused by copying and pasting some code,

1. This `printf()` statement would cause undefined behavior

   ```
   printf("\nEnter the price per %s: ", &tokenSold);
   ```

   because you are passing the correct address but the pointer type is wrong so pointer arithmetic will cause undefined behavior inside `printf()`

   ```
   printf("\nEnter the price per %s: ", tokenSold);
   /* remove the & --------------------^ here */
   ```
2. You passed a double pointer to `addPres` but you never dereference it to access the actual poitner, which is what you want to modify, that is causing both, undefined behavior and the observed effect of an empty list, since once the function returns it did not alter the original poitner, you should access the double pointer with the dereference operator inside this function, for example instead of

   ```
   if (tip == NULL)
   ```

   it has to be

   ```
   if (*tip == NULL)
   ```

   and the same applies for every access inside this function.

   - How did I find out all these problems so quickly?

     > Because I compiled your programs with compiler warnings enabled and it started showing those problems.
   - Will there be other issues in your code?

     > Yes probably, but you need to fix these first.
3. You `fflush(stdin)`, a very common mistake which seems to come from some tutorials or books or online resources, the standard clearly states that `fflush()` is for output streams, and the behavior is undefined for input streams, the following was taken from the C11 draft

   > **7.21.5.2 The fflush function**
   >
   > 2. If stream points to an output stream or an update stream in which the most recent
   >      operation was not input, the `fflush` function causes any unwritten data for that stream
   >      to be delivered to the host environment to be written to the file; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Thanks so much! It's working now, also that fflush(stdin) is what my first teacher taught me, he wasn't very good, this is evident of that.

Comment: @user2603473 I didn't know that before becoming an active member of this site, but there are a lot of bad c teachers or books and also online courses and tutorials, a lot of them.

Comment: @user2603473 your teacher tell you about [MSDN compiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yky46tz.aspx), where where `fflush(stdin)` is fully defined (as a non-standard extension on that platform) --  **If the stream is open for input, fflush clears the contents of the buffer.**

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Interesting, I did not know that, but a c teacher should not teach non standard compiler specific features. What do you think?

Comment: @iharob teaching and using non-standard compilers like MSDN is not wrong. I believe OP's course is more about programming than C, and Teachers get limited time to interact and transfer knowledge, it is student's responsibility to  explore further in-dept from book. And if one really concern -- it could be a good science question that "why does standard not define `fflush(stdin)`"? where it is possible.